# creating fast successive beeps in matlab/psychtoolbox

Tags: matlab, audio

I have to create beep arrays of differing numerosity.  I determine how many beeps will be
played, the duration of each individual beep and the inter-beep duration online.  However,
these all have to be played really fast, both the intervals and the durations will be in between 0.01secs-0.2secs.  The sound function of matlab does not allow you to take very small breaks in between as even if you play two sound functions one after each other without putting a small break by a timer, it takes longer than the timing I need.  Any ideas?  I would really appreciate any help...

Comment: What I have done before, is rather than trying to produce a sound of a different frequency, different duration, and wait time individually, is compose them into one array (This is nice for making random game music). Is this an option?

Answer (score 2):

To guarantee a given spacing, I think that you need to assemble the waveform.  I suspect a lot of variation in the time it takes to startup the `sound` function.

As an example, the function below should give you a good start:

```
function beep_series(specs)
%BEEP_SERIES  Create a series of beeps
%    BEEP_SERIES([FREQ_HZ, VOL, DUR_SEC, PAUSE_SEC]) creates a series of
%    beeps from an N-by-4 spec matrix, where the colums represent:
%        frequency
%        volumne (0-1)
%        beep duration
%        pause duration,

freq = specs(:,1);
volume = specs(:,2);
duration = specs(:,3);
trailingGap = specs(:,4);

SAMPLE_FREQ = 8192;
totalTime = sum(duration) + sum(trailingGap);
x = zeros(ceil(totalTime*SAMPLE_FREQ),1);

curBeepStartTime = 0;
for ix = 1:length(freq)
    numSamples = round(duration(ix)*SAMPLE_FREQ);
    x( round(curBeepStartTime*SAMPLE_FREQ + (1:numSamples))  ) = ...
        volume(ix) * sin(    (1:numSamples)  *  (2*pi*freq(ix)/SAMPLE_FREQ)   );
    curBeepStartTime = curBeepStartTime + duration(ix) + trailingGap(ix);
end

sound(x, SAMPLE_FREQ)
```